# WP-Bakery - Add custom colors to buttons with template colors

Tags: php, functions, customization

I'd like to add custom colors to the wp-bakery-front editor.
Adding all the colors works but I just want to add the color of the current template.

My function.php in the theme has the folowing function to add the colors to the button settings.

```php
function change_vc_button_colors() {
    $param = WPBMap::getParam( 'vc_btn', 'color' );
     
    $param['value'] = [];
        
    $param['value'][__('Custom-Color-1', 'theme-name' )] = 'active-orange';
    $param['value'][__('Custom-Color-Template1-blue', 'theme-name' )] = 'active-orange';
    $param['value'][__('Custom-Color-Template2-green', 'theme-name' )] = 'active-orange';
    $param['value'][__('Custom-Color-Template3-orange', 'theme-name' )] = 'active-orange';
    $param['value'][__('Custom-Color-Template4-yellow', 'theme-name' )] = 'active-orange';
    
    //Finally "update" with the new values
    vc_update_shortcode_param( 'vc_btn', $param );
}
```

[image]

Is it possible to ask in this function the current used template name and add only this colors (like over a if-clause) ?

Becuase this don't work:

```php
global $template
if (str_contains($template, 'template.php')) 
{
    $param['value'][__('Custom-Color-1', 'theme-name' )] = 'active-orange';
}
```

or with

```php
get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
```

When the page has the themplate "template1" it should be like this (so only one additional color):
[image]

Comment: What did the WP Bakery support team say when you asked them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: They have not yet responded. Therefore I ask here.